# Understanding the Hexagonal AutoMapping in SKTileMaps

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I've read Ray Wenderliche's tutorial on SKTileMaps and I've been interested in creating something hex based. I've been messing around with some simple graphics for a tile set, but I've been unable to figure out what the auto-mapping for Hex's means. For the square tiles it was easy to understand from tutorials but the variations of Hex's boggles my mind. Anyone have any insight or examples? These are all the images. I'm not exactly sure what a complete tileset would look like and as such I'm having trouble drawing it. Ive tried looking at apple documentation for SKTileGroupRules, but it also lacks information on this detail.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: interested in question.. !

Comment: I'm shocked no one has any kind of experience with this.. :/

Comment: everybody too busy making physics games maybe :(

Comment: I'm following this now, because I'm just starting to work with hex tilemaps game nodes. Not a lot of info out there yet. I guess us gamers from the 90s die hard.

Comment: Yeah honestly, I ended up giving up on the auto-tile-mapping thing. I kept making different photoshop images but they didn't really quite fit. Sucks that apple has close to 0 documentation on this. You essentially have to either write your own library for tilemaps or used something like Tiled. But I tried it and it didn't really have what I needed.